# Python-behave tag's Or logic does not appear to be working

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

```
Feature: Addition tests

@one
Scenario: Add two numbers to pass
  Given two numbers to add
  When 2 and 3 are added together
  Then the sum should be 5

@two
  Scenario: Add two numbers to fail
  Given two numbers to add
  When 2 and 3 are added together
  Then the sum should be 6
```

Running >> behave --tags="@one" (or behave --tags=one)
Gives me

```
@one
Scenario: Add two numbers to pass  # features/Add.feature:4
  Given two numbers to add         # features/steps/Maths.py:4 0.000s
  When 2 and 3 are added together  # features/steps/Maths.py:8 0.000s
  Then the sum should be 5         # features/steps/Maths.py:12 0.000s

 @two
 Scenario: Add two numbers to fail  # features/Add.feature:10
   Given two numbers to add         # None
   When 2 and 3 are added together  # None
   Then the sum should be 6         # None
```

As expected.

An yet Running >> behave --tags="@one or @two"
Gives me

```
@one
Scenario: Add two numbers to pass  # features/Add.feature:4
  Given two numbers to add         # None
  When 2 and 3 are added together  # None
  Then the sum should be 5         # None

@two
Scenario: Add two numbers to fail  # features/Add.feature:10
  Given two numbers to add         # None
  When 2 and 3 are added together  # None
  Then the sum should be 6         # None
```

This should execute both scenarios and as per every tutorial this seems to be the way to run multiple scenarios. Am I missing something obvious here (and i'm definitely running "or" and not behave --tags="@one and @two")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this feature is documented in the [**latest** version](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags) documentation, it is not available in the [**stable** version](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags), which at the time of writing this answer is 1.2.6. Your issue has been documented a while ago in [github and closed](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/763).

Chances are you have got version 1.2.6 or lower installed, in which case you should use one of the the following for logical OR:

```
behave --tags=one,two

#that's the same thing as
behave --tags @one,@two
```

`behave --tags-help` gives some useful info too.

If you would like to upgrade, uninstall the current `behave` version and install the latest available tagged release (at this point in time v1.2.7.v1).

```
sudo pip uninstall behave
pip install git+https://github.com/behave/behave@v1.2.7.v1
```

Instructions and other install options [here](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#using-the-github-repository).

Comment: 0buz - Thanks ever so much. Absolute lifesaver! I'm indeed using 1.2.6. I have been writing some ridiculously convoluted tags and scenarios to get around this issue. But no more.

Comment: As of 2024, stable version appears to be still 1.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, I just can't comment yet.

I'm having a similar issue.

`behave --tags="@one and @two"`

running "and" ^^^ seems to skip all tests even though I have tests that have both tags for certain.

Comment: Reading from behave --tags-help (as accepted answer) for "and" use "behave -t one -t two"